# how to fetch data from DataSet using Linq in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code,

I am trying to write a Linq query to fetch data from a DataSet, or to fetch data from a List, but unfortunately when I try to use the keywords of the Linq i.e (from, select, where) the framework tell me that there exist a syntax error.

For example if I write the sentence ***from Table in tab.AsEnumerable() select;***  the framework says the type or namespace name 'from' could not be found.

I am new to Linq, so please could any one guide me and help me to solve this problem.

any page, link tutorial could help me to learn Linq would be appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Globalization;

namespace linqToDataSet
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='C:\Users\Spider Wep\Documents\linqTodataset.mdf';Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30";
            using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                c.Open();
                // 2
                // Create new DataAdapter
                using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(
                    "SELECT * FROM [Table]", c))
                {
                    // 3
                    // Use DataAdapter to fill DataTable
                    DataSet t = new DataSet();
                    a.Fill(t);

                    DataTable tab = t.Tables["Table"];
                    List<int> integers = new List<int> { 1,2,3};
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `select` you need to select *something*, for example:

```
var rows = (from Table in tab.AsEnumerable() select Table);
```

And it's important to note that `LINQ` uses deferred execution which means this query won't be executed until you iterate over the result using `foreach`, or use some method to force execution immediately like `ToList` or `ToArray`.

If you are new to this there are some useful resources that you might wanna have a look:

- [LINQ (Language-Integrated Query)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx)
- [Deferred Execution and Lazy Evaluation in LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943859.aspx)
- [Query Syntax and Method Syntax in LINQ (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx)
- [Edulinq from Jon Skeet](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/)

Answer (score -2):

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = 
  @"Data Source=ALIPC;initial catalog=TrainingDatabase;integrated security=True";       

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "select * from question";
cmd.Connection = conn;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);            
return dt;

//   you can call this method wherever

classname c=new classname();

foreach(datarow dr in c.methodname().rows)
{
    user u=new user();
    u.userid = dr["userid"];
    list.add(u);
}
return list;
```